# Using FileUtils in eclipse

Tags: java, ant, jar, fileutils

When trying to use `FileUtils` I get "cannot be resolved" error.

[image]

Then, how do I install `FileUtils` library to be able to use it in Eclipse? I see it is an Ant utility, but I am not sure how many jars I need to install.

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Open the project's properties---> Java Build Path ---> Libraries tab ---> Add External Jars

will allow you to add jars.

You need to download [commonsIO from here](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Answer (score 9):

Now selenium supports following code:

```
FileHandler.copy(src, dest);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Add above dependency in pom.xml file

Comment: An answer should explain what it is doing.

Comment: Choose the latest version from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io).

Answer (score 1):

`FileUtils` is class from apache `org.apache.commons.io` package, you need to download `org.apache.commons.io.jar` and then configure that `jar` file in your class path.

Answer (score 1):

I have come accross the above issue. I have solved it as below. Its working fine for me.

1. Download the 'org.apache.commons.io.jar' file on navigating to [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils] [ http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonsiojar.htm ]
2. Extract the downloaded zip file to a specified folder.
3. Update the project properties by using below navigation
   Right click on project>Select Properties>Select Java Build Path>
   Click Libraries tab>Click Add External Class Folder button>Select the folder where zip file is extracted for org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.zip file.
4. Now access the File Utils.

Answer (score 0):

For selenium automation users

1. Download Library file from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonsiojar.htm
2. Extract
3. Right click on the proj name from the explorer >> Build path >>Config Build Path

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using FileUtils.copyfile(src,trg);
use following in Selenium java
FileHandler.copy(src, dest);