# Use FileUtil for android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use [this FileUtils](http://source.android.com/reference/com/android/tradefed/util/FileUtil.html#hardlinkFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29).

But I can't find how. I can not import the package of it.
I searched for a .jar or library, which i can import to my Eclipse.

I need the FileUtils to create hardlinks.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13166389/4385913)

Comment: I will try it ans will report the result. Thx

Comment: It doesn´t work. These are other FileUtils. (look the posted link)

Answer (score 0):

`FileUtils` is from Apache CommonsIO. You need to download it from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Now right click your project, select `Properties`, then click `Java Build Path`, then click `Libraries` tab. Now you should see a button `Add External Jars` at the right side. Click on it, and add the CommonsIO jar.
You are done!

Comment: Unfortunetly this does not come by default. This is the reason for my question

Comment: @Jeremy How i mentioned above. These FileUtils from ApacheCommonsIO doesn´t equals to the FileUtils i asked for. Or do i overlook sth on the side?

Comment: @TheTanic Oh yea... you're right. What is your min SDK version?

Comment: @Jeremy My current min SDK is 11