# FileUtils not showing suggestion to import predefined class for Screenshot functionality in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, fileutils

I am not allowed to use FileUtils in the program and error is shown when doing so. Even no suggestion is showing to import this pre-defined Class. I tried to search the solution but what I found was to import the class. But in my case even suggestion is not showing to import any class. Hovering on the "FileUtils" shows the suggestion to create FileUtils class/interface. Below is my code:

```
 package captureScreenshot;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; //Getting Error at this line
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class FacebookScreenshot {

@Test
    public void captureScreenshot() throws IOException
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstname']")).sendKeys("Anil Kumar");

    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyfile(source,new File("./Screenshots/facebook.png")); //Getting error at this line

    driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FileUtils in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166350/using-fileutils-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### FileUtils Class

[**`FileUtils`**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) Class is defined in **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils** which provides the *general file manipulation utilities* in the following areas :

- writing to a file
- reading from a file
- make a directory including parent directories
- copying files and directories
- deleting files and directories
- converting to and from a URL
- listing files and directories by filter and extension
- comparing file content
- file last changed date
- calculating a checksum

**org.apache.commons.io** is bundled along with **selenium-server-standalone-x.y.z** by default and available ready to use.

But the behavior you are observing is pretty much inline with your *usecase* where you mentioned that you are *not allowed to use **FileUtils** in the program*. It can be either of the scenarios as mentioned below :

- Incase you are using *JARs* from **selenium-java-3.9.1** client, the *JAR* containing **org.apache.commons.io** is not being added to your project.
- Incase you are using *Maven* with **selenium-java-3.9.1** client dependency the modules containing *FileUtils Class* have been excluded.

For the following above mentioned reasons, when you mention **FileUtils** in your program it doesn't show any suggestion to import the class. Moreover if you forcefully provide the import, it will show error on that line.

Comment: Importing org.apache.commons.io does the job. Thanks DebanjanB.

Answer (score 1):

The line `FileUtils.copyFile();` has been updated to `FileHandler.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes with Selenium Latest version we should use *FileHandler.copy()*
It works and doesn't throw any error.

```
// Take Screenshots example
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileHandler.copy(scrFile, new File("<your path>\\screenshot.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

download maven commons-io  jars from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
and add jars to your build Path in your project

Answer (score 0):

In the above FileHandler.copy(scrFile, new File("\screenshot.png"));
here copy -the method copy(File, File) is undefined for the type FileHandler is occured

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
Files.copy(sourcefile,destinationfile);

This will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).